Java Spring Boot gRPC service not being created
I am trying to implement gRPC into my Java Spring Boot application (Maven), after compiling the .proto file and building the project, all the classes are being created except for the service in the proto.
Here is my proto file:
syntax = "proto3";
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "nasta.grpc.welcome";

message Message {
  int32 id = 1;
  string name = 2;

}
message Welcome{
  string welcome_name = 1;
}
message  WelcomeMessage
{
  string welcome_name = 1;
}
service SayWelcomeService {
  rpc SayWelcome(Message) returns (WelcomeMessage){};
}

Here is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo.grpc.server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo.grpc.server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>1.62.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.62.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.62.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.devh</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-server-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
            <configuration><protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.25.3:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                </protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.62.2:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                <protoSourceRoot>src/main/resources/proto</protoSourceRoot>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I saw some other posts and tried removing <outputDirectory> from pom.xml but still didn't work

Please update your question to include a minimal set of output from Maven and before|after folder trees.

In your proto file, package name and outer class name are missing. After adding those to your proto file,
syntax = "proto3";

package proto; //create a package and set its name here.

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "nasta.grpc.welcome";
option java_outer_classname = "WelcomeProto";

message Message {
  int32 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
}

message WelcomeMessage {
  string welcome_name = 1;
}

service SayWelcomeService {
  rpc SayWelcome(Message) returns (WelcomeMessage) {}
}


try to use this build in your pom.xml file
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.1</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.6.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.25.1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
        <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
        <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.65.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

and try to compiling once more.

Also please check here to see more examples: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java

By default, generated code is under build/generated/source/proto/main, did you check there? Did you configure your IDE to delegate build to Maven? Also, try build directly with Maven

mvn protobuf:compile


Yes I did check there .I am using IntelliJ so I Maven is bundled with it, I can't use mvn command
